# Предупреждения Parameter '...' is never used в Borland

Tags: borland, c++

Что нужно сделать в borland, если:

> `Warning..\..\DOCume~1\ADMIN\0016~1\C\PROJEKT\CONVERSI.CPP: Parameter 'nNumberofArgs' is never used`
> `Warning..\..\DOCume~1\ADMIN\0016~1\C\PROJEKT\CONVERSI.CPP: Parameter 'pszArgs' is never used`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно ничего не делать, либо как-то использовать эти параметры. Можно понизить уровень предупреждений в настройках, на крайний случай.

Answer (score 2):

Предупреждение говорит о том, что параметр не используется. Чтобы предупреждение исчезло, надо либо удалить параметр из кода, либо использовать его.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант добавить в этих местах
    #pragma argsused